# Anorm seq of NamedParameter

Tags: scala, anorm

I'm trying to create a dynamic query with dynamic parameters in anorm. That's why I need the parameters I'm working with, as a List. Following the doc [Scala Anorm 2.5.x](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAnorm#edge-cases)

This is the parser that I'm using

```
val parser = SqlParser.folder(Map.empty[String, (String, Any)]) { (map, value, meta) =>
    Right(map + (meta.column.alias.getOrElse(meta.column.qualified) -> (meta.clazz, value)))
}
```

this code works

```
val parameters: Seq[NamedParameter] = Seq[NamedParameter] ("column1" -> 1, "column2" -> "2", "column3" -> true)
val resultSet: List[Map[String, Any]] = SQL(query).on(parameters: _*).as(parser.*)
```

But this one doesn't compile

```
case class SearchParameter(sqlColumn: String, value: Any)

val searchParameters = List(SearchParameter("column1", 1), SearchParameter("column2", "2"), SearchParameter("column3", true))
val parameters: Seq[NamedParameter] = Seq[NamedParameter] (searchParameters.map(field => field.sqlColumn -> field.value): _*) // this line doesn't compile
// type mismatch, expected: Seq[NamedParameter], actual Seq[(String, Any)]
val resultSet: List[Map[String, Any]] = SQL(query).on(parameters: _*).as(parser.*)
```

If I try to cast the Seq in this way

```
val parameters: Seq[NamedParameter] = Seq[NamedParameter] (searchParameters.map(field => field.sqlColumn -> field.value): _*).asInstanceOf[NamedParameter]
```

It compiles but at runtime, it throws java.lang.ClassCastException

Answer (score -1):

Casting when a type mismatch compilation error occurs is not a solution.

The way to fix it is to use the appropriate type. There, the type of `SQL(query).on(parameters: _*)` is `anorm.SimpleSql[anorm.Row]` (not at all `List[Map[String, Any]]`).

It's highly recommanded to first read the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAnorm).

Comment: Sorry, I haven't copyied all the code and I forgot to put the parser that I've created a few lines before and the .as(parser.*) that returns the type List[Map[String,Any]]. I will edit that.
My problem is the line that I've commented in the second example
    
`val parameters: Seq[NamedParameter] = Seq[NamedParameter] (searchParameters.map(field => field.sqlColumn -> field.value): _*)`

As I said, I'm following the documentation. this is the example that I'm trying to use

`val nps = Seq[NamedParameter]( // Tuples as NamedParameter before Any
  "a" -> "1", "b" -> "2", "c" -> 3)`

Comment: As indicated in the documentation, that's unsafe to do so

Comment: I'm not casting any type. I'm trying to use the third example in the doc like this `Seq[NamedParameter] (searchParameters.map( field => field.sqlColumn -> field.value): _*)` but I can't understand why it doesn compile with the message `type mismatch, expected: Seq[NamedParameter], actual Seq[(String, Any)]`

Comment: Please read [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAnorm#Edge-cases). Your `SearchParameter` is either a generic type (with instances with heterogeneous type parameters for `SearchParameter("column1", 1)` with `1: Int`, for `SearchParameter("column2", "2")` with `"2": String`, for `SearchParameter("column3", true)` with `true: Boolean`) or a class with an `Any` for `value`. Any way that leads to `searchParameters.map(field => field.sqlColumn -> field.value)` losing type safety and being `Seq[(String, Any)]` ... `Any` not being a type valid as `ParameterValue`.